# set Matlab WindowButtonDownFcn and preserve default behavior

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, undocumented-behavior

can I manually set `WindowButtonDownFcn` and selectively overwrite the right or middle-click, while preserving default behavior? Ultimate goal would be to copy figure to clipboard on some click.

```
set(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@(src,~) disp(src.SelectionType)); %this seemingly always overwrites default behavior of figure click
```

I tried this with following error msgs (scroll right)

```
listener(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn',@(src,~) disp(src.SelectionType)) %Event 'WindowButtonDownFcn' is not defined for class 'matlab.ui.Figure'.
listener(get(gcf,'parent'),'WindowButtonDownFcn',@(src,~) disp(src.SelectionType)) %Event 'WindowButtonDownFcn' is not defined for class 'matlab.ui.Root'
handle(gcf).addlistener(handle(gcf),'WindowButtonDownFcn',@(src,~) disp(src.SelectionType)) %Unrecognized method, property, or field 'addlistener' for class 'matlab.ui.Figure'.
```

and several more permutation using `handle` and `event.listener` with no success

*Tested in Matlab 2019a.*

**EDIT: here's a template function to use with modifiers based on matlabgui's kind answer**

```
%copies figure to clipboard when [control]+[right-click] anywhere on figure window (and leaving default functionality intact)
figure; plot(randi(100,1,100)) %random figure
addlistener ( gcf, 'WindowMousePress', @(src,~) myFavFunc(src,[]))

function myFavFunc(src,~)
if strcmp(src.SelectionType,'alt') && numel(src.CurrentModifier)==1 &&  strcmp(src.CurrentModifier,'control')
    print -clipboard -dmeta
    disp('copied figure to clipboard')
end
end
```

Comment: I also tried using listener() functions, but coulnd't get it to work

Comment: listeners are the way to go - so show us what you tried and that way we can show you what you did wrong

Comment: done, if I get it correctly, i mainly don't know what `WindowButtonDownFcn` is a method of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know why Matlab hide some of the events for figures, you can get a list here:

```
  hFig = figure;
  mc = metaclass(hFig);
  disp ( {mc.EventList.Name}' ) ;
```

From that info you can then add a listener to the mouse press event:

```
hFig = figure;
addlistener ( hFig, 'WindowMousePress', @(src,~)disp('myCallback' ))
```

That will leave the standard figure callback alone, instead of the disp command get it to run a function where you look at the figure property `SelectionType` to determine which mouse button was pressed.  You could extend it to use the `CurrentModifier` property to determine if `Ctrl`, `Shift` or `Alt` was pressed to further customise it.

Comment: Very interesting! It should be noted that any callback set for the `'WindowButtonDownFcn'` also appears to still function simultaneously, so whatever that is set to do (i.e. zooming, rotating) will happen *as well as* whatever is done in the listener for a given mouse operation.

Comment: indeed this is brilliant, I adapted the code for a function using `SelectionType` and `CurrentModifier`

Comment: Followup question: how do I query what is stored in `WindowMousePress` for the current figure?

Comment: Just look at the property.  Am I missing what you mean?